# mpdf codeigniter writehtml error

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

I am trying to pass my database info as an object to mpdf writehtml . here is my controller

```
$query_cond = array('c_id' => $id, );
$final = $this->CI->myfunction->get($query_cond,TRUE);
foreach ($final as $row)
{

  //$content = $this->load->view('pdf/pdf_view', array('final' => $row,), TRUE); 
  $content[] = (object) array(
    'content' => $this->CI->load->view('pdf/pdf_view', array(
      'final' => $row, 
      ), TRUE),
  );
}

//var_dump($content);

$this->load->library('pdf');
$pdf = $this->pdf->load();
$pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
$pdf->WriteHTML($content);
//$pdf->Output('mypdf.pdf', 'I');
```

the writehtml is not working properly Its giving me the error:

```
Message: preg_match() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given
Filename: mpdf/mpdf.php
Line Number: 21999

Message: mb_convert_encoding() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given
Filename: mpdf/mpdf.php
Line Number: 30677
```

Would be great if you could help me to get rid of this error.

Above content object I tried to pass the data not in object but that logic passing only one row.. I need to pass all row array corresponding to that id . How can I convert object arry to string in codeigniter and pass it to view??

Comment: I think that if mpdf works without object than you need to give it data not in a object.

Comment: can u plz provide me the code snippet..Above content object I tried to pass the data not in object but that logic passing only one row.. I need to pass all row array corresponding to that id.

Comment: can't you do something like a tostring of an array or object to generate a string?

Comment: Or even do a loop for $pdf->WriteHTML for each row you've got?